Is the term "Memra" (Word) in the Targum Jerusalem Deuteronomy 24:7 connected with Avot De Rabbi Natan 34:9 and Sefer Yetzirah 1:9?
Targum Jerusalem Deuteronomy 26:17 goes like this:

"You have chosen the Word of the Lord to be king over You this day, that he may be your God."

Does this unique concept called "Word" have something to do with Avot De Rabbi Natan 34:9:

"The Holy Spirit is referred to by ten terms. And they are: Parable, Metaphor, Riddle, Speech, Saying, Splendor, Command, Burden, Prophecy, Vision."

Or Sefer Yetzirah 1:9:

"Ten Sefirot-Without-What: One – Spirit of the Living God, blessed and glorified is the name of the life of the worlds, voice and spirit and speech. This is the Holy Spirit."?

And could it be that its origin can be traced from works of Philo Judeaus, Midrash Tanchuma Bo 5:3, Midrash Tanchuma Buber Yitro 17:1, and the Divine Voice in Apocalypse of Abraham?

Welcome to MiYodeya. It is always helpful in a question like this one to give the Hebrew text of the language quoted as well as the English translation. That helps to clarify the specific problem and will generally also provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Sefaria at https://www.sefaria.org/Targum_Jerusalem%2C_Deuteronomy.26.15-17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en has the Hebrew text יַת מֵימְרָא דַיְיָ אַמְלִיכְתּוּן עֲלֵיכוֹן יוֹמָא דֵין לְמֶהֱוֵי לְכוֹן לֶאֱלָהָא:  So I can see the word “memra” (which is central to your question) from the Hebrew text and which is otherwise not in your question

Please rewrite everything in the original language. Otherwise, it's not Targum, it's a Targum on a Targum.

I have tried to clarify the question and have also tried to answer it

The root מלך in Aramaic has a broader semantic range than "king", and it includes meanings related to counsel and authority. A more accurate translation of the Targum (26:17) would be, "You have accepted the authority of the word of the Lord upon yourselves, so that He be your God." The antecedent of "He" is "the Lord" (as opposed to the dualistic interpretation now fashionable among evangelical missionaries that identifies the antecedent as "the word"). The context of the passage in Deut supports the reading that the Israelites expressed fealty to the one and only God by accepting His Torah.

The OP is alluding to Segal's "Two Powers in Heaven" argument that a biune godhead was a prevalent Jewish viewpoint by 1st century. This position has since been popularized by Christian theologians who seek to undermine Jewish monotheism by grafting a biune interpretation of Philo's "Logos" (which itself was borne out of Platonic Hellenism) onto Pharisaical thinking by conflating concepts and distorting biblical and rabbinic texts. The purpose of this is to claim that "rabbinic monotheism" is a revisionist 2nd century theology crafted by Jews for the purpose of denying the divinity of Jesus.

Based on the extracts copied and pasted below, my answer is that I can see no link at all between Targum Jerusalem Deuteronomy 26:17, Avot De Rabbi Natan 34:9 and
Sefer Yetzirah 1:9
Sefaria at https://www.sefaria.org/Targum_Jerusalem%2C_Deuteronomy.26.15-17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en has the Aramaic original text of the Targum Deuteronomy 26:17 as:

יַת מֵימְרָא דַיְיָ אַמְלִיכְתּוּן עֲלֵיכוֹן יוֹמָא דֵין לְמֶהֱוֵי
לְכוֹן לֶאֱלָהָא:

With the English as follows:

You have chosen the Word of the Lord to be King over you this day,
that He may be your God.

Sefaria at https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_DeRabbi_Natan.34.8-9?lang=bi
has the original text and translation of Avot d’Rabbi Natan 34:9 as follows:

עשרה שמות נקרא רוח הקדש. אלו הן משל. מליצה. חידה. דיבור. אמירה. תפארת.
ציווי. משא. נבואה. חזיון:  The Holy Spirit is referred to by ten
terms. And they are: Parable, Metaphor, Riddle, Speech, Saying,
Splendor, Command, Burden, Prophecy, Vision.

Sefaria at https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yetzirah.1.8-9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
Has Sefer Yetzirah in the original and in English as follows:

עשר ספירות בלימה, אחת רוח אלהים חיים ברוך ומבורך שמו של חי העולמים קול
ורוח ודבור וזהו רוח הקדש:  Ten Sefirot-Without-What: One – Spirit of
the Living God, blessed and glorified is the name of the life of the
worlds, voice and spirit and speech. This is the Holy Spirit.

